# How to link to language's homepage for untranslated page in django-cms?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

Within django-cms I have two languages, with one page in Dutch currently not translated into English. When viewing this page, language_chooser does not provide a link for the English translation (as there is not). However, I would like to link the link to the English translation to link to the homepage (or some other English page if it makes sense). Now I could create the needed template tag myself, or some template trickery, but I think this problem has been solved before. Sadly though, I could not find any example of such a solution.

Language chooser is used like this:

```
<p><small>Choose your language: {% language_chooser %}</small></p>
```

The default template used by this template tag ([source on github](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templatetags/menu_tags.py#L289)):

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for language in languages %}
<a href="{% page_language_url language.0 %}"{% ifequal current_language language.0 %} class="current"{% endifequal %}>{{ language.1 }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Rendered html (note the empty href for link to English):

```
<p><small>Choose your language: 
<a href="">English</a>
<a href="/nl/contact/" class="current">Nederlands</a>
</small></p>
```

Comment: I worked around this by modifying the source of django-cms, but that doesn't seem a sustainable solution. I also flagged this an issue in django-cms: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1087

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the following:

Make an own template tag for `page_language_url` by subclassing it's existing tag, put it in a template tag file in one of your projects apps, let's call it `menu_extra_tags.py`:

```
from django import template
from menus.templatetags.menu_tags import PageLanguageUrl
from classytags.arguments import Argument
from classytags.core import Options

register = template.Library()

class PageLanguageUrlAsVariable(PageLanguageUrl):
    name = 'page_language_url_as_variable'
    options = Options(
        Argument('lang'),
        'as',
        Argument('varname', resolve=False),
    )
    def render_tag(self, context, **kwargs):
        varname = kwargs.pop('varname')
        url = super(PageLanguageUrlAsVariable, self).render_tag(context, **kwargs)
        context[varname] = url
        return ''
register.tag(PageLanguageUrlAsVariable)
```

Now in your language chooser template do:

```
{% load menu_tags menu_extra_tags %}
{% for language in languages %}
    {% page_language_url_as_variable language.0 as pageurl %}
        <a href="{% if pageurl %}{{ pageurl }}{% else %}/{{ language.0 }}/{% endif %}"{% ifequal current_language language.0 %} class="current"{% endifequal %}>{{ language.1 }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

That will redirect you to `/en/` (the home page in English) if the English translation for this page is not available.

Comment: Although I was hoping for a clean solution (DRY), this will get the job done.

Comment: How is that not DRY enough? Granted, you need to write your own template tag (although it's only a tiny part of the template tag) and probably that tag should be in core already. Other than that this solution seems pretty straight forward and clean to me

Comment: Granted, your solution is clean. I share your opinion that it should have been in core, which would solve my 'issues' with your solution not being DRY. Thank you. I will link to your solution in the issue I raised for django-cms.

Comment: @ojii pls explain answer for a guy new to django , i tried but i don't know , how to include menu_extra_tags.py , i tried to include it in an app  and m getting an error that menu_extra_tags is not defined.

Comment: @WebDev you need an app in Django (an app in ``INSTALLED_APPS``) which has at least a ``models.py`` in it (so it gets detected). Then make a package ``templatetags`` in that app with an empty ``__init__.py`` file in it and the ``menu_extra_tags.py``. Please also refer to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/