# How to hide untranslated languages from language chooser in django-cms

Tags: django-cms

Does anyone have a clue, how to modify behaviour of django-cms language chooser, wich always shows whole list of languages even if certain page don't have translation for some of language/s?
I want to hide unavailable translations on current page, and show only translated variants, but can't find any information about this in django-cms documentation or internet. Is there any filters for language chooser tag?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same strategy as described in [How to link to language's homepage for untranslated page in django-cms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016169/how-to-link-to-languages-homepage-for-untranslated-page-in-django-cms/8124011#8124011)

Instead of redirecting to the homepage, you would just not show that language.